# I'm building a Shiny app in R and keep getting an error that "non-numeric argument to binary operator"

Tags: r, shiny

I'm creating a Shiny app in R but every time I try to load it i get the error "non-numeric argument to binary operator" - this error seems to be occurring in the renderPlot section in the server area.

I'm in the preliminary stages of building this and I'm not an expert in Shiny by any means. The app is supposed to load a chart based on the values from the projections that I'm scraping from FantasyPros. It was working when I was using regular data (as opposed to reactive data), but I can't seem to nail down the reactive part. Any help is appreciated!

```
if(interactive()){

        ## load required packages
        library(shiny)
        library(tidyverse)
        library(ggplot2)
        library(ggrepel)
        library(dplyr)
        library(agridat)
        library(rvest)

        ## load latest projections from fantasypros
        scrape_projections <- function(position, week) {

            if (position == "qb") {
                naming <- c("", "PASS", "PASS", 'PASS', "PASS", "PASS", "RUSH", "RUSH", "RUSH", "", "")
            } else if (position == "rb") {
                naming <-  c("", "RUSH", "RUSH", "RUSH", "REC", "REC","REC", "", "")
            } else if (position == "wr") {

                naming <- c("", "REC", "REC","REC", "RUSH", "RUSH", "RUSH", "", "")
            } else {
                naming <- c("", "REC", "REC","REC", "", "")
            }

            # Be nice
            Sys.sleep(1)

            message(glue::glue("Scraping projected stats for {position} wk: {week}!"))

            url <- glue::glue("https://www.fantasypros.com/nfl/projections/{position}.php?week=draft")

            url %>%
                read_html() %>% 
                html_table() %>% 
                .[[1]] %>% 
                filter(X1 != "") %>%
                set_names(nm = .[1,]) %>%
                .[2:length(.$Player),] %>% 
                set_names(., paste({naming}, names(.), sep = "_")) %>% 
                rename("Player" = "_Player", "FL" = "_FL", "FPTS" = "_FPTS") %>% 
                mutate(position = toupper({position}),
                       week = week) %>% 
                mutate(team = str_sub(Player, -3),
                       team = str_extract(team, "[[:upper:]]+"),
                       Player = str_remove(Player, team),
                       Player = str_trim(Player)) %>% 
                select(Player, team, position, week, everything()) %>%
                rename_all(tolower)
        }

        # define inputs
        position <- c("qb", "rb", "wr", "te")
        week <- "draft"

        # crossing for all combos of inputs
        crossing(position, week)

        # scrape the data
        projections <- crossing(position = position, week = week) %>% 
            pmap_dfr(scrape_projections) %>%
            mutate_at(vars(pass_yds, rush_yds, rec_yds), str_remove, ",") %>% 
            mutate_at(vars(pass_att:rec_tds), as.numeric) %>%
            mutate_at(vars(team:position), as.factor) %>% 
            select(-c("week")) %>% 
            as_tibble()

        ## set all NA values to 0
        projections[is.na(projections)] = 0

        ## set_vor function
        set_vor <- function(points_table, vor_baseline = NULL, vor_var = c("fpts", "floor", "ceiling")){
            if(is.null(vor_baseline))
                vor_baseline <- default_baseline

            vor_var <- match.arg(vor_var)

            vor_tbl <- select(points_table, "player", "position", vor_var) %>%
                rename(vor_var = !!vor_var) %>% group_by(position) %>%
                mutate(vor_rank = dense_rank(-vor_var), vor_base = vor_baseline[position]) %>%
                filter(vor_rank >= vor_base - 1 &  vor_rank <= vor_base + 1)  %>%
                summarise(vor_base = mean(vor_var)) %>%  ungroup() %>%
                select(position, vor_base) %>% inner_join(points_table, by = c("position")) %>%
                rename(vor_var = !!vor_var) %>%
                mutate(vor = vor_var - vor_base,
                       rank = dense_rank(-vor), !!vor_var := vor_var) %>%
                select(player, position, vor, rank) %>% rename_if(is.numeric, funs(paste(vor_var, ., sep = "_"))) %>%
                ungroup()

            return(vor_tbl)
        }


        ## 
        ## ui.R: defines a layout that will resize according to the size of the browser window; 
        ##       all the app code will be placed within the brackets of this

        ui <- fluidPage(
            titlePanel("2020 Fantasy Football Draft Evaluator - created by Sam Hoppen"),
            sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(
                    p("Select draft settings"),
                    selectInput(inputId = "league_size",
                                label = "1. Select league size",
                                choices = c("8", "10", "12", "14", "16"), selected = "12"),
                    selectInput(inputId = "draft_position",
                                label = "2. Select draft position",
                                choices = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16"), selected = "1"),
                    radioButtons(inputId = "scoring",
                                 label = "3. Select scoring type",
                                 choices = c("Non PPR", "Half PPR", "Full PPR"), selected = "Half PPR"),
                    tags$p("Select starting lineup"),
                    radioButtons(inputId = "starting_qbs",
                                label = "Number of starting QBs",
                                choices = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
                                selected = "1",
                                inline = TRUE),
                    radioButtons(inputId = "starting_rbs",
                                label = "Number of starting RBs",
                                choices = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
                                selected = "2",
                                inline = TRUE),
                    radioButtons(inputId = "starting_wrs",
                                label = "Number of starting WRs",
                                choices = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
                                selected = "3",
                                inline = TRUE),
                    radioButtons(inputId = "starting_tes",
                                label = "Number of starting TEs",
                                choices = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
                                selected = "1",
                                inline = TRUE),
                    radioButtons(inputId = "starting_flex",
                                label = "Number of starting flex spots",
                                choices = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
                                selected = "1",
                                inline = TRUE),
                    radioButtons(inputId = "starting_superflex",
                                label = "Number of starting superflex spots",
                                choices = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"),
                                selected = "0",
                                inline = TRUE),
                    radioButtons(inputId = "bench_players",
                                 label = "Number of bench spots",
                                 choices = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"),
                                 selected = "6",
                                 inline = TRUE),
    #                actionButton(inputId = "draft",
    #                             label = "Click to begin drafting!"),
                    selectInput("draft_pick_1",
                                "Round 1 Selection",
                                c("Select player" ="", projections$player)),
    selectInput("draft_pick_2",
                "Round 2 Selection",
                c("Select player" ="", projections$player)),
    selectInput("draft_pick_3",
                "Round 3 Selection",
                c("Select player" ="", projections$player)),
    selectInput("draft_pick_4",
                "Round 4 Selection",
                c("Select player" ="", projections$player)),
    selectInput("draft_pick_5",
                "Round 5 Selection",
                c("Select player" ="", projections$player)),
    selectInput("draft_pick_6",
                "Round 6 Selection",
                c("Select player" ="", projections$player)),
    selectInput("draft_pick_7",
                "Round 7 Selection",
                c("Select player" ="", projections$player)),
    selectInput("draft_pick_8",
                "Round 8 Selection",
                c("Select player" ="", projections$player)),
    selectInput("draft_pick_9",
                "Round 9 Selection",
                c("Select player" ="", projections$player)),
    selectInput("draft_pick_10",
                "Round 10 Selection",
                c("Select player" ="", projections$player)),
    selectInput("draft_pick_11",
                "Round 11 Selection",
                c("Select player" ="", projections$player)),
    selectInput("draft_pick_12",
                "Round 12 Selection",
                c("Select player" ="", projections$player)),
    selectInput("draft_pick_13",
                "Round 13 Selection",
                c("Select player" ="", projections$player)),
    selectInput("draft_pick_14",
                "Round 14 Selection",
                c("Select player" ="", projections$player)),
    selectInput("draft_pick_15",
                "Round 15 Selection",
                c("Select player" ="", projections$player))
                ),
                mainPanel(
                    plotOutput("draftPlot")
                )
            )
        )

        ## server
        server <- function(input, output) {
            #            input$draft
            #            isolate(
            default_baseline <- reactive(
                c(QB = (input$league_size*(input$starting_qbs + input$starting_superflex)*1.25),
                  RB = ((input$league_size*(input$starting_rbs + input$starting_flex)*1.5) + (input$starting_superflex*input$league_size*0.5)),
                  WR = ((input$league_size*(input$starting_wrs + input$starting_flex)*1.5) + (input$starting_superflex*input$league_size*0.5)),
                  TE = ((input$league_size*(input$starting_tes +(input$starting_flex*0.5))) + (input$starting_superflex*input$league_size*0.25)),
                  DST = (input$league_size*0.5),
                  K = (input$league_size*0.25)))

                vor_table <- reactive(
                    set_vor(projections,
                                     vor_baseline = default_baseline(),
                                     vor_var = "fpts"))
            #            drafted_players <- projections %>% 
            #                filter(player = c(input$draft_pick_1,
            #                                  ))
            output$draftPlot <- renderPlot({
                ggplot() +
                    geom_smooth(data = vor_table(),
                                aes(x = as.numeric(fpts_rank), y = as.numeric(fpts_vor)),
                                color = "firebrick",
                                linetype = "dashed",
                                size = 1,
                                method = "loess",
                                formula = y ~ x,
                                se = FALSE) +
                    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 200),
                                    ylim = c(0, 150)) +
                    labs(x = "Player Draft Selection",
                         y = "Player Value Over Replacement",
    #                     caption = "Data from nflscrapR",
                         title = "2020 Fantasy Football Draft Evaluator",
                         subtitle = "Created by @SamHoppen") +
                    theme_bw()
            })
        }
    }

    ## run app
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This might be hard to debug(need to go through all the code to figure out what's failing). Likely doing maths on a character/factor. Is there some sort of `traceback`?

Comment: @NelsonGon unfortunately I'm not sure there is a traceback. Like I mentioned, the error comes somewhere in the server section of the code. It's either with the default_baseline, vor_table, or output$draftPlot section because the error is appearing where the plot should be loading.

Comment: use the `browser()` function to debug yourself. just put it somewhere inside of the server and go through the code

Comment: @mnist it appears to be in the "output$draftPlot" section. I can step through the first two server sections without any issues but then get the error "Warning: Error in +: non-numeric argument to binary operator" when stepping through the plot creation

Comment: I rather guess its inside of your reactive. Reactives are evaluated only when they are called. check the values of your inputs. they are most like NULL initially. You will learn a lot by debugging shiny.

Comment: The choices of the radioButtons are text, you must convert them to numeric (`as.numeric()`) before using them in calculation

Comment: @HubertL does that need to be done in the reactive part under the server section or does that occur in the UI part?

Comment: In the server part, replace all calls to `input$xxx` by `as.numeric( input$xxx)`

Comment: @HubertL perfect, thanks! Out of curiosity, do I still need to do this if I change the input type to “numericInput”?

Comment: If you use `numericInput` you don't have to use `as.numeric`